# Trying to place a form at the top of a div

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I have a small box placed at the bottom of the page. I am trying to place a form right above a div but the form keeps jumping into the bootstrap div.

this is the html attempt
EDITTED:
I also want the row across the form to have a background color as thesame with the breadcrumbs but it is not showing

```
<div style="padding:1px; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <form class="rightiest" method="post" action="/logout">
            <input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Leave Group"/>
    </form>
</div>
 <div class="breadcrumb">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="container" style="text-align: center;font-size: 80%;">
                <strong> Please hold we will soon attend to you shortly</strong>



                </div>
            </div> 
</div>
```

This is the css controlling the form

```
 form.rightiest {float:right; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:7px;}
```

with the above, the form keeps overlapping into the div. Please how can I place the form right above the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the float.

```css
     form.rightiest {float:right;
       margin-top:0px;
       margin-bottom:7px;}
    
    .breadcrumb {
       clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<form class="rightiest" method="post" action="/logout">
            <input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
    </form>
     <div class="breadcrumb">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;font-size: 80%;">
                    <strong> Please hold we will soon attend to you shortly</strong>
    
    
    
                    </div>
                </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I am applying a background color but it is not showing

Comment: <div style="padding:1px; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
 <form style="background-color: #F2F2F2;" class="rightiest" method="post" action="/logout">
        <input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
</form>
</div>

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the BG colour please @user6731422

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your floats.

```
.breadcrumb {
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the bottom margin of your form and possibly the padding on the form too. If there is top padding or top margin on your breadcrumbs that may also need to be changed.